# Have $f(cx,cy)=cf(x,y)$, and prove that $x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=f$

Tags: calculus

So we have a function $f(a,b)$ so that

$$f(cx,cy)=cf(x,y)$$for all $x,y,c$, and we have to show that:

$$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=f$$

What I tried:
I defined $F(x,y,z)=cf(x,y)$, so we get that $F_c'=f(x,y)$.

On the other hand, $F(x,y,z)=f(cx,cy)$. So, what I'd like to say is that

$$(*)F_c'=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial c}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial c}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y$$

To get that

$$F_c'=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y=f(x,y)=f$$
And prove the statement.

The thing is, in $(*)$ I used the chain rule as if $cx$ is a function of $x$ namely $x=g(c)=cx$ (and the same regarding $y$), and I'm not sure that's a "legal step" or makes any sense. In any case, I'd like to see your own solutions to the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I see no defect in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to worry. It comes down to a common problem with partial derivatives, that when we have functions with complicated arguments, there isn't a good way to use Leibniz's notation unless we give all the functions new names: it is normally better to consider both differentiation with respect to a variable and differentiation with respect to the contents of a function's argument (i.e. the "slot" in the function where we put the inputs).

To do this the Leibnizian way, let $g(c)=cx$, $h(c)=cy$. Then let
$$ F(c) = f(g(c),h(c)). $$
Now use the chain rule:
$$ F'(c) = g'(c) \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}(g(c),h(c)) + h'(c) \frac{\partial f}{\partial h}(g(c),h(c)). $$
Putting in the definitions, $g'(c)=x$ and $h'(c)=y$, so this is
$$ F'(c) = x \frac{\partial f}{\partial (cx)}(cx,cy) + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial (cy)}(cx,cy), $$
which looks pretty horrible. Putting $c=1$ gives
$$ F'(1) = x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y), $$
which gives the result you want when you use the equality $F(c)=cf(x,y)$. But can we really just put $c=1$ when it lives in a derivative?

---

It's worth noticing that what we actually took were partial derivatives with respect to the contents of the "slots" in $f(\cdot,\cdot)$. In mathematics, much moreso than physics, for example, functions are not inherently dependent on certain letters: $(x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ is the same function as $(z,w) \mapsto f(z,w)$ (at least if we have no more information that tells us that $z,w$ are actually different from $x,y$). And the derivatives of this function therefore also do not depend on the particular labels we have used to represent the inputs.

Hence the preference for $f'(a)$ over its Leibnizian equivalent $\left. \frac{df}{dx} \right|_{x=a}$ or $\frac{df}{dx}(a)$. While it doesn't matter too much if $x$ is the only variable in the world, as soon as you expand the scope to something as simple as $f(cx)$, you suddenly have a problem: how do you express the derivative of this when $x$ changes in terms of the derivative of the original function? Thankfully we have a way to do this already: $f'(a)$ is defined as
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} $$
no matter what $h$ is. Thus if $g(x)=f(cx)$, we may write
$$ g'(x) = cf'(cx) $$
with no ambiguity. To do the same in Leibniz's notation would require writing $d/d(cx)$, which is pretty ugly even in this simple case.

---

So, the sensible thing to do is to introduce a similar notion for partial derivatives. Hence, for example, we can define
$$ \partial_1 f(a,b) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h,b)-f(a)}{h}, $$
and in the same way for other "slots". This makes life much easier: we no longer have to worry about what the contents of the slot are. With this notation,
$$ F'(c) = x \partial_1 f(cx,cy) + y \partial_2 f(cx,cy), $$
the partial derivatives have nothing to do with $c$, and so we don't have to worry about just evaluating this at $1$,
$$ F'(1) = x \partial_1 f(x,y) + y \partial_2 f(x,y) = x \partial_x f(x,y) + y \partial_y f(x,y), $$
since the arguments in the slots really are now just $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thanks this really helped me understand.